# Поиск в предложений и слов с спецсимволами в elasticsearch

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, поиск, elasticsearch

Есть готовый индекс эластика использующийся для автодополнений. Разообрался как сделать фильтрацию по одному слову состоящему из букв, но не могу понять как сделать поиск так что бы можно было сделать поиск слов с пробелами. Например могу в поле names найти по запросу "Иванов" запись вида "Иванов Иван Иванович", но если я задам в поиск "Иванов Иван" то ничего не вернётся. Кусок кода:

```
SearchSourceBuilder search = SearchSourceBuilder.searchSource();
BoolQueryBuilder query = new BoolQueryBuilder();
String value = "Иванов Иван"; //строка которая ищется в индексе
query.must(QueryBuilders.regexpQuery("names",".*" + value.replaceAll("([+\\-!\\(\\){}\\[\\]^\"~*?:\\\\]|[&\\|]{2})", "\\\\$1") + ".*"));
search.query(query);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас используется стандартный анализатор для поля names, он разбивает фразу на три токена "Иванов", "Иван", "Иванович". А ваш запрос выглядит так:

```
{ "regexp": { "names": ".*Иванов Иван.*" }}
```

Естественно ни с одним токеном совпадения не будет найдено.
Вижу два варианта решения проблемы:

1. Исправить маппинг, добавив виртуальное поле names.raw для поиска. В нем будет один токен "Иванов Иван Иванович", т.к. не используется анализатор.

   ```
   {
       "mappings": {
           "names": {
               "type": "string",
               "fields": {
                   "raw": {
                       "type": "string",
                       "index": "not_analyzed"
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Поиск по этому виртуальному полю.

```
query.must(QueryBuilders.regexpQuery("names.raw",".*" + value.replaceAll("([+\\-!\\(\\){}\\[\\]^\"~*?:\\\\]|[&\\|]{2})", "\\\\$1") + ".*"));
```

2. Без изменения маппинга. Разбивать ключевое слово так как это делает стандартный анализатор. В простейшем случае разбивка на фразы, разделенные пробелом. И делать более сложный поиск по каждой такой фразе.

   ```
   {
     "query": {
       "bool": {
         "should": { "regexp": { "names": ".*Иванов.*" }},
         "should": { "regexp": { "names": ".*Иван.*" }}
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Или использовать must вместо should, в зависимости какая логика вам требуется.

**Обратите внимание, что логика поиска немного отличается в этих двух вариантах.**

Comment: Отлично. +1 Вашему ответу. Хотел написать ответ, но знаний эластика не хватает на столь полный ответ как у Вас.